# Why won't the if in my if-then statement for my loop work?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

The `else` is always reached, the `if` condition isn't doing anything.

This is part of a larger function. In the HTML, there are 2 inputs: age and phone number. In the script, `numberArray` consists of the variables for these two values (age and phone number).

This for statement is supposed to make the output appear on the id card (in my comment) look like this: "Age: 17". The `else` condition works fine and shows up as "Phone Number: [numberinput]" so I don't understand what's wrong with the `if` condition.

```
function idCard() {
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
var phoneNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value);
var age = parseInt(document.getElementById('age').value);

document.getElementById("postFullName").innerHTML = firstName + lastName;
document.getElementById("postAddress").innerHTML = address;
document.getElementById('postAge').innerHTML = age;
document.getElementById('postPhoneNumber').innerHTML = phoneNumber;

var numberArray = [];
numberArray.push("age");
numberArray.push("phoneNumber");
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (numberArray[i] <= 100){
        document.getElementById("postAge").innerHTML = "Age: " + age;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("postPhoneNumber").innerHTML = "Phone Number: " + phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your HTML page have an element called `postAge`?  Does `numberArray[]` have first two elements less than or equal to 100 ?

Comment: Do you have a `numberArray` which contains numbers under 101? Do you have an element with the ID `postAge`? Do you have a variable `age`? Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: share you other code with us. what about `age` and `phoneNumber`?

Comment: Pl add an example of what might be the possible values in `numberArray`. It will help with understanding the question better.

Comment: Did you called the `js` file inside `HTML`

Comment: can you please provide us much more details?

Comment: i do have an element called postAge. Basically (bear with me, im very new to this this is for an assignment) I am creating a form that will take the inputs for age and phone number and make them show up on a sort of id card. The section I showed is required. If the value inputted for age is less than or equal to 100, it is supposed to come out as "Age: [whatever age given"

Comment: Do you have age & phoneNumber variables?

Comment: more details provided.

Comment: This should be like this `numberArray.push(age);numberArray.push(phoneNumber);` , why extra double quotes ?

Comment: i have no idea, but i dont think its an issue, as the code still works fine, its just the if statement. I figured it was improper syntax??

Comment: really it has no issue if you use double quest on your age and phoneNumber while pushing it to numberArray? could you plz try to `console.log(numberArray);` after that push of **string** age and phoneNumber

Comment: nothing changes after adding console.log(numberArray);

Comment: @saintpepperoni I've updated my answer based you latest code with proper comment. Hope it helps now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52940118/1138192

Comment: thank you @don'tangryme that helped a bunch, you're awesome

Comment: @saintpepperoni I'm helping you out from the **beginning** and now you're accepting others answer. good job. :( Best of luck

Comment: Learn basic debugging. console.log() would have clearly showed issues.

Comment: @don'tangryme dont be mad :^( you helped alot, I just was foolish and didn't see how it would help until i got really desperate. I'm very new to this. excuse my childish nature, but i am a kid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood your question then** What about this? If I pass two numbers **one less than 100** and other **greater than 100**. So in that case the former will treat as age and the later will be a phone number.

By the way on your code you've used a block of code like this which is wrong in this content because it'll produce `['age','phoneNumber'];` not the number version of `age` and `phoneNumber`

```js
numberArray = [];
numberArray.push("age");
numberArray.push("phoneNumber");
console.log(numberArray); // will produce ['age','phoneNumber'];
```

```js
var phoneNumber = 4567890; // I assume this is what you get as phoneNumber
var age = 15;              // I assume this is what you get as age
numberArray = [];
numberArray.push(age); // see change here without quotes
numberArray.push(phoneNumber); // see change here without quotes

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  if (numberArray[i] <= 100) {
    document.getElementById("postAge").innerHTML = "Age: " + numberArray[i];
  } else {
    document.getElementById("postPhoneNumber").innerHTML = "Phone Number: " + numberArray[i];
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="postAge"></div>
<div id="postPhoneNumber"></div>
```

Comment: By Number array consists of two variables, age and number. So if i put 15 for the age, 15 is what is used for the first value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

`numberArray[i]` is currently a string "age" or "phoneNumber". Seems like a minor typo, I'm guessing you meant to push the variables?

```
var numberArray = [age, phoneNumber];

// or if you must push
var numberArray = [];
numberArray.push(age);
numberArray.push(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: the assignment says i have to push to prove that i can or something, but i thought that I already had var numberArray = [];
numberArray.push("age");
numberArray.push("phoneNumber")

Comment: @saintpepperoni sorry, sloppy copy-pasta on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `if` statement is not running is because your `numberArray`'s first two elements are greater than 100 - I can't tell because you haven't shared that part of your code, but that's what you'll find if you post it.

Comment: My arrays elements are dependent on what is inserted in the input. If i input 15, i want it to come up as "Age: 15" but all it shows is "15", while still showing the input for the phonenumber fine.